# Mobile: I want to have a browser open googleMaps or AppleMaps

Tags: android, wordpress, google-maps

On Mobile devices, I want to be able to have my customer click on a link and it opens their Maps on their phone and give directions to a location.  Right now I have to either use a link that will be for Android or for Apple, is there any way to have a link that opens the persons map function whatever device they are using.

```
  var MyPlace = new google.maps.LatLng(43.016488,-84.729201);

  var image = 'http://lansingparadeofhomes.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/ParadeofHomes1.png';
  var Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: MyPlace,
       url: 'http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=43.016488,-84.729201&amp;ll=&',
       title: 'LansingParadeofHomes1',
       map: map,
       icon: image
  });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html):

Show a location on a map

To open a map, use the ACTION_VIEW action and specify the location information in the intent data with one of the schemes defined below.

Action
ACTION_VIEW
Data URI Scheme
geo:latitude,longitude
Show the map at the given longitude and latitude.
Example: "geo:47.6,-122.3"

geo:latitude,longitude?z=zoom
Show the map at the given longitude and latitude at a certain zoom level. A zoom level of 1 shows the whole Earth, centered at the given lat,lng. The highest (closest) zoom level is 23.
Example: "geo:47.6,-122.3?z=11"

geo:0,0?q=lat,lng(label)
Show the map at the given longitude and latitude with a string label.
Example: "geo:0,0?q=34.99,-106.61(Treasure)"

geo:0,0?q=my+street+address
Show the location for "my street address" (may be a specific address or location query).
Example: "geo:0,0?q=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway%2C+CA"

Note: All strings passed in the geo URI must be encoded. For example, the string 1st & Pike, Seattle should become 1st%20%26%20Pike%2C%20Seattle. Spaces in the string can be encoded with %20 or replaced with the plus sign (+).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think this is for just opening a Android map. I am looking for a way to code it so that it will open a map on an iphone or an android...Whichever device you are on.

Comment: You want an Android bit of code to do something on an iPhone?  Good luck with that

Comment: I was looking for a way to code it so that it will open the map function of a mobile device... is that even possible?

Comment: I just gave you that code - for an Android app. You want iOS functionality? That's a different question